# Printing tuples in for loops python

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

Hi I'm learning Python via a Youtube Tutorial series and [the tutorial I just viewed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJQgP27SYQI&list=PLGzru6ACxEAKorNc8bMhv2vTa0qGbjBcD&index=111) explained how to print `tuple`s embedded within a `list`. The publisher of video explains two ways, specifically:

```
>>> a = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
>>> for (b, c, d) in a:
...     print(b,c,d)
... 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
>>> for nums in a:
...     a,b,c = nums
...     print(a,b,c)
... 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I attempted a third way:

```
>>> for nums in a:
...     a,b,c = nums
...     print(nums)
```

but received this error

"Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

I sense that the takeaway is that I should make sure to always print `tuple`s in `tuple` form but that seems like if could be really tedious if it were a really long `tuple` (or `list` of `tuple`s).  What is wrong with my attempt?

Comment: Your choice of variable naming is bad. You're re-declaring `a` as an inner-loop variable, so `a` on the second iteration becomes an integer.

Comment: well, the examples you provided are all not useful. You would normally just do `for nums in a: print(nums)`. The problem here is that you've overwritten your `a` variable, which used to be a list, with the final result of your last for-loop.

Comment: Okay, I see now.  Thanks! Changing this makes it print with the parentheses whereas the other methods don't.  Why is that? @coldspeed

Comment: Because in one, you are using the `print` *function* and passing it three arguments. In the other, you are passing it a *single argument*, which happens to be a tuple. You can *unpack the tuple into the function call* like so: `for nums in a: print(*nums)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this works just fine

```
a = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
for nums in a:
    a,b,c = nums
    print(nums)

(1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6)
(7, 8, 9)
```

Second, if don't have the need to expand the tuple (or in general any iterable), you don't have to. This is equivalent to the snippet above. The for-loop just iterates across the first level of objects, whatever that is (tuples in your case):

```
a = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
for nums in a:
    print(nums)

(1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6)
(7, 8, 9)
```

Third, it's a bad practice to reuse the variable `a` in the loop that you've defined outside the loop. Afterwards, outside the loop, `a` will be what it was during the last iteration of the loop (which is 7). That's a drawback of *duck typing*, i.e.  missing type declaration in python compared to C for example

```
a = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
for nums in a:
    a,b,c = nums
    print(nums)
print a

(1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6)
(7, 8, 9)
7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
a = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
for tuplet in a:
    print (tuplet)
```

This will print (1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6)
(7, 8, 9) in tuplet form

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, you've clobbered your list variable `a` by re-assigning `a` within your loop. You should be able to fix this by using a different variable name, for example:

```
a = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
for nums in a:
    x,y,z = nums
    print(x,y,z)
```

When I did this, I got the following output:

> (1, 2, 3)
>   (4, 5, 6)
>   (7, 8, 9)